# Is "on" the correct preposition in "I met her on a bright April morning"?

Tags: prepositions

Since we use the preposition 'in' with morning as well as with months, I wanted to be sure if 'on' is the correct preposition when the morning is qualified by a month instead of the usual phrases that have days or dates like on Friday morning, on the morning of November 15th, etc.

I would also like to know if the abovementioned sentence is phrased correctly in the first place.

Thank you

Comment: IMO the phrasing is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. One might say, "I met her *in the* morning," being specific about the time. However, "I met her *on a * morning," one among many mornings, is used with "on". Not sure I can give a rule *why*, though. It is "English as she is spoke," https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_She_Is_Spoke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct to use "on" in that sentence.

In that context, "morning" is used *metonymically* to mean "an April day in the morning". It refers to the day in terms of what time of day it was.